# How to express utter exhaustion with a topic

Tags: idiom-requests

What is an idiom or a saying to express utter exhaustion with a topic? Like "fed up with beating a dead horse", only pithier, and doesn't seem to condone cruelty to animals?

For example:

> ab2 is {*fed up with beating a dead horse*} over [single-word-requests]

---

*Credit to [ab2 for the question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/are-single-word-requests-bad-or-are-they-great?cb=1#comment46103_10999). And no, **"covfefe"** is not an acceptable answer, I want a real one.*

Comment: sick and tired of .....have had enough of...

Comment: "I've had it up to here with..."?

Comment: How does hitting a horse corpe condone cruelty to animals? its an ex-horse, passed on, ceased to be etc (continue ad tedium)

Comment: I like 'sick to my back teeth', which describes exactly the same situation as 'throw up in my mouth a little bit' without generating the same visceral response.

Comment: 'Alternatives to beating a dead horse' --->http://www.rayfowler.org/2008/02/15/12-alternatives-to-beating-a-dead-horse/

Comment: @Spagirl - In terms of condoning cruelty to animals, "beating a dead horse" comes from the phrase "there's no point beating a dead horse" which implies that there *is* point in beating a live horse; hence cruelty.

Comment: @AndyT I suppose that's true on the dead horse. Possibly I've rarely heard the whole phrase, or even though of there *being* a full phrase. The UK version I'm used to is just 'you're flogging a dead horse there'. Anyway, on the vomitus side, I've done you an answer.

Comment: It's flogging a dead horse in Canada too.  I've never heard beating a dead horse before.

Comment: @Spagirl - I've now googled the "there's no point in ..." part. Turns out it's relatively obscure (1000 hits each for "beating" and "flogging" the dead horse). So clearly my earlier statement was rubbish, and the original phrase doesn't contain "there's no point in". Chalk another one up for AndyT talking rubbish as though he knows what he's talking about. It's a good thing answers require research - it's saved me from a lot of other incorrect statements on this site!

Comment: Brilliant question!  I wish I had asked it!  (+1 and *)

Comment: @AndyT According to shanty collector Stan Hugill the first month of a voyage when the sailors worked off their advance was called the 'horse' and the rest of the voyage was the period after the horse had 'died'. Hugill says there used to be a ceremony at the end of the first month during which an effigy of the horse was dragged to the gunwale and thrown overboard while [this shanty](http://www.shanty.org.uk/archive_songs/poor-old-horse.html) was sung; but exactly what relationship exists between this ceremony and the expression 'flogging a dead horse' I wouldn't like to say.

Comment: @BoldBen - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flogging_a_dead_horse#Earlier_meaning) mentions the same, but like you I can't see the connection to "flogging". Sounds like coincidence to me.

Comment: @AndyT "Flogging" is easy to understand, particularly in an historic maritime setting. Discipline on sailing ships was  maintained using vicious corporal punishment including flogging with a whip. The point of the 'dead horse' is that after the advance had been worked off the captain could use financial penalties to maintain order so flogging sailors after the 'horse was dead' was less necessary and less efficient. My uncertainty is about  the origin of the phrase, I think it might be a land expression that went to sea rather than the other way round which is often suggested.

Comment: Why not use: to deplete the vein of this topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A phrase I greatly enjoy is 'Sick to the back teeth'

> [sick to the teeth (or back teeth) of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sick_to_the_teeth_%28or_back_teeth%29_of)
>
> PHRASE
>
> *British*
>   Extremely annoyed about or tired of.
>
> ‘I'm just sick to the
>   back teeth of waiting’

I particularly like the fact that it describes exactly the same physical situation as 'threw up/was sick in my mouth a little bit' without invoking the same visceral response, familiarity lets its grossness fly under the radar.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you are looking for idioms rather than single words, but since you are also looking for 'pithy' and since I found myself in the Dictionary of the Scots Language for other reasons, I thought I'd offer up the verb '[to Scunner](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/scunner)'

> *V. tr.* To cause a feeling of repulsion, aversion or loathing in (a
>   person), to disgust, nauseate, surfeit:
>
> *'The smell of his body scunnered them.'*
>
> *in fig.* usage, to make (one) bored, uninterested or antipathetic.
>
> *He canna stand Tories by naething, they fair scunner him.*
>
> to bother, to take up (someone's) time or interest.
>
> *I canna be scunnered wi = I have no time for, no patience with.*

And in the noun form 'a Scunner'

> n. 1. A feeling of disgust, surfeit or nausea, loathing
>
> *Like an auld dog that trails its useless ugsome carcass into some bush or bracken, no to gie living things a sconner wi' the sight o't
>   when it's dead.*
>
> *in a fig. sense*: repugnance, distaste, dislike, a loss of interest
>   or enthusiasm 
>   *Many of them have taken a scunner at religion because they took a scunner at it at school.*

In your example sentence the verb form would render as

> ab2 is scunnered with single-word-requests

and as a noun

> ab2 took a scunner at single-word-requests

*(nae auld dogs were skelpit in the writing of this answer.)*

Comment: Interesting. I've only ever come across the word before in the [pictsie dialect](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Pictsies#Dialect_and_language) in Terry Pratchett's Discworld series, where it means "a generally unpleasant person".

Comment: @AndyT I see nearly added that it came to an international audience via the wee free men...

Comment: A gem of a new word!  But I am not scunnered with SWRs; I am scunnered with talking about them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of **Exasperated**

> **Exasperate**
>
> ɪɡˈzasp(ə)reɪt,ɛɡˈzasp(ə)reɪt/
>
> irritate intensely; infuriate. *"this
> futile process exasperates prison officers"*

ab2 is *exasperated* with single-word-requests

Comment: I'm looking for a colourful idiom rather than a single word.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Dakota Indians have a saying of 'dismounting from a dead horse' when they wish to cease from a pointless activity.

> The tribal wisdom of the Dakota Indians says when you discover you’re riding a dead horse, the best strategy is to dismount.

Various alternatives are [discussed here](http://www.rayfowler.org/2008/02/15/12-alternatives-to-beating-a-dead-horse/) in regard to horses and their welfare when misused in idioms. The quote above is taken from this link.

'**I am fed up going round in circles**' is a common (and humane) way of saying the same thing.