# What's the one-word for a plan which is always discussed and planned but it never happens?

Tags: single-word-requests

My cousin just keeps on planning that we will go here, do this, do that..... but it never happens. And in the next meet also the same cycle repeats. So I was just wondering what is the appropriate word for the things that are planned but never happen?

Comment: How would you use the word in a sentence?

Comment: @Lawrence How about... "You're always planning something and never do it! It's all just a ________, isn't it!"

Comment: What makes people think that English has a one-word for anything they could imagine? That's what phrases and clauses and sentences are for.

Comment: @JohnLawler 'What makes people think that English has a one-word for anything they could imagine?' I don't know, but there should be a word for it.

Comment: Pie-in-the-sky, though that's longer than scam or crock.

Comment: And, of course, it has a song associated with it.

Comment: Not much one word but https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/pie-in-the-sky

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There are probably many phrases and expressions that would work here, but if you insist on a single word you must include a sample sentence as required by the SWR tag...for more info hover your cursor over the single-word-request tag at the bottom of your post

Comment: "jam tomorrow"  https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/jam-tomorrow.html

Comment: "Castles in Spain", albeit three words? The question is clear; it seems unnecessary to specify further how it may be used. Such a specification would add nothing to the challenge. I therefore feel it rigidly over-formal and wantonly discouraging to a newcomer to the site to have closed it rather than answer it. I suggest reopening.

Comment: It sounds more like an **unkept promise**. As an adjective, _unfulfilled_ and _unrealized_ are related, as in "unrealized plan". It would depend on the context and the type of word.

Comment: Fantasy........

Comment: It's akin to the fictional Jarndyce v Jarndyce probate case  (Dickens; _Bleak House_).

Comment: It's akin to the fictional Jarndyce v Jarndyce probate case  (Dickens; _Bleak House_). // 'Flogging a dead horse (also beating a dead horse) is an Anglophone idiom that means that a particular effort is futile, a waste of time without a positive outcome....' [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flogging_a_dead_horse)]. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dead%20horse) lists the bare noun or noun phrase 'dead horse'.

Comment: Closely related: [How to express utter exhaustion with a topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419559/how-to-express-utter-exhaustion-with-a-topic). 'Going round in circles'. // 'Covering the same ground'.

Answer (score 2):

> **VELLEITY**
>
> a wish or inclination not strong enough to lead to action.
>
> - ‘*the notion intrigued me, but remained a velleity*’

Definition supplied by *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/velleity)*

Comment: Actually this a good guess. Unfortunately, I've never heard this word before and I don't think many others will have either, so I'm not sure how useful this answer is. Still... +1

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetical plan? :P  No, I'm kidding. I would say the word would describe your cousin rather than the plans he keeps repeating.

The first word that comes to mind is "flakey" which is *slang* - the non-slang terminology for it is undependable, basically. Another way to describe him (meaning the same thing, just a different word) would be to call him unreliable or fickle.

If you didn't want to be overly harsh or rude, you could say he's uncertain, indecisive, unpredictable, or inconsistent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the word **materialize** is more apt in this context. It means:

> to begin to happen or exist : to occur or become real — usually used
> in negative statements

For example,
She was promised a promotion but it never materialized.
Source: https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/materialize

So, maybe you mean:
We had planned a vacation together, but the plan did not materialize.

Comment: You only cited one of your sources for this answer. Can you cite the other one? Also, please use blockquotes for direct quotes (instead of nothing and instead of code formatting since it's not code)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **warhorse**.

> *warhorse*
>
> ...
>
> 3: [often premodified by 'old'] something ([perhaps] a work of art or musical composition) that has
> become overly familiar or hackneyed due to much repetition in the
> standard repertoire [/course of events]

[[Merriam-Webster; adjusted slightly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warhorse)]

Usually used in the arts, but readily transferrable:

> - *Is the Atlantic City boardwalk and beach safe at night?*
> - Oh, my goodness, not this old warhorse again. It's been debunked on this forum many times. Hint: crime figures are compared to the city's
>   population, but don't take into account the number of visitors to the
>   city.

[[ShiannM; Trip Advisor ... Forum](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g29750-i78-k9736994-o30-Is_the_Atlantic_City_boardwalk_and_beach_safe_at_night-Atlantic_City_New_Jersey.html)] (punctuation corrected)